# Using singleton vs provider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I'am working on a music player app  in flutter. I'm using [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) plugin to get all mp3 files and to play music.
I created a separate **AudioFunctions** class to do all these processes as shown below.

```
class AudioFunctions{
  FlutterAudioQuery audioQuery;
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  List<SongInfo> songs;

AudioFunctions(){
  this.audioQuery = FlutterAudioQuery();
  this.audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  this.songs = [];
}

getLocalSongs() async => this.songs = await audioQuery.getSongs();

String optimiseSongTitles(int index){
  String songTitle = '';

  if (this.songs[index].displayName.contains('-')){
    songTitle = this.songs[index].displayName.split('-')[0];
  }
  else if(this.songs[index].displayName.contains('_')){
    songTitle = this.songs[index].displayName.split('_')[0];
  }

  return songTitle;
}

void playLocalSong(String path){
  audioPlayer.play(path,isLocal: true,);
}

void pauseLocalSong(){
  audioPlayer.pause();
}

Stream<Duration> getLength() {
  return audioPlayer.onDurationChanged;
}

Stream<Duration> getPosition() {
  return audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged;
}

Future<int> changeSlider(Duration d){
  return audioPlayer.seek(d);
}

}
```

Now I can access this class to retrieve relevant data .
Running `getLocalSongs` saves a list of all local songs to the `songs` variable in the class. However I have to run this each time I create object of AudioFunctions. So, on each screen.

**Should I use a singleton or provider**? Since I'am new to flutter, I don't know how to work with either of them and I have doubts whether if I can use objects in provider.

Show some love and help out a noob

Comment: You can use whatever you want inside providers. The issue with singletons is testing, which will be difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a singleton is a good choice here because you probably don't want to call AudioPlayer() on every page again.

```dart
class AudioFunctions {
  static AudioFunctions _instance = AudioFunctions._();
  FlutterAudioQuery audioQuery;
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  List<SongInfo> songs;
  
  static AudioFunctions get instance => _instance;

  AudioFunctions._() {
    this.audioQuery = FlutterAudioQuery();
    this.audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    this.songs = [];
  }

  getLocalSongs() async => this.songs = await audioQuery.getSongs();
}
```

To access AudioFunctions now you can call `AudioFunctions.instance`.
I have changed your constructor to `AudioFunctions._()` so that it can no longer be called outside the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What did you mean by "no longer be called outside the file." It would be helpful if you can direct me to any articles regarding this. I believe I have a lot to learn about this.

Comment: It is not necessary, but it helps to keep a clear overview of your project. In your case you don't need to call the constructor anywhere, because you always have your Singleton instance. The article [A tour of the Dart language](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts) describes private identifiers: `Unlike Java, Dart doesn’t have the keywords public, protected, and private. If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it’s private to its library. For details, see Libraries and visibility.`

Comment: As an example, the variable: `int _privateVariable;` due to the `_` also only accessible within the file.

Comment: I ran into an error. I tried the following code to call the function `getLocalSongs`
But I get this error
`instance member cannot be accessed using static access`
 I am using this code in the splash screen of the app.
`@override`
`void initState() {`

`    super.initState();`

`    initializePlayer();`
`  }`

`  void initializePlayer() async {`

`    AudioFunctions.instance.getLocalSongs();`

`  }`

Comment: Sorry for the code formatting I cant get it to work

Comment: Sorry, I messed up my example and unfortunately I didn't test it myself before. I set the instance and the get function static and now it works for me. I corrected my answer.

Comment:  I tried making _instance static did'nt know I had to make the getter static too. I went on with using provider and its working now. Should I change it to Singleton? Is it more efficient? Thanks again